# media query iPad in landscape mode and above

Tags: ipad, css, stylesheet, media-queries

My CSS looks like this:

```
/* width 1024px up to 1600px */
/* main CSS */

/* width 1601px up to 1920px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1601px) {
/* CSS */
}

/* wider than 1920px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1921px) {
/* CSS */
}

/* mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
/* CSS */
}
```

Everything works as expected except the iPad in landscape mode which shows the mobile version although the mobile version only targets devices up to 1023px. I want the iPad to show the main css.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this problem with the code you've provided.  Can you please provide a demonstrative example?

Comment: Please take a look at the production site: http://www.adglomera.be/vanluyten2/. It works when I resize my browser to 1024px but when I check on an iPad (I've checked on more than one) the mobile version is shown.